# connect to website through proxy in vb.net script in SSIS

Tags: xml, vb.net, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am trying to write an SSIS package that connect to an XML feed to download FX rates and import them into an SQL table.

i have the code below, but cannot figure out how to implement logging in through a proxy.

if anyone can think of an easier way to do the above, i'm more than willing to give it a try.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Net



Public Class ScriptMain

Public Sub Main()


    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDataDocument, strXML As String
    Dim client As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()

    Dim cr As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password")
    Dim pr As New System.Net.WebProxy("proxy", 8080)

    pr.Credentials = cr
    client.Proxy = pr

    xmlDoc = New XmlDataDocument
    xmlDoc.Load("http://themoneyconverter.com/GBP/rss.xml")
    strXML = CType(xmlDoc.InnerXml, String)
    Dts.Variables("strXMLData").Value = strXML
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub

End Class
```

Many thanks.

Comment: So you're saying the code works, but you're interested in implementing logging?

Comment: no, i'm interested in logging into the corporate proxy so i can access the xml file and download it into SSIS and on to the SQL server

Answer (score 1):

You can use the credentials of the currrent login with:

```
Imports System.Net

Dim Pr As New System.Net.WebProxy(Proxy, Port)
Pr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = Pr
```

'  WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy is the proxy settings used by xml.Load()

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly in SSIS 2012 - thanks

Aside from the Imports System.Net in the declaration, my final code looked like this :

```
 Dim Proxy As String, Port As Integer

 Proxy = "EnterYourProxyServerName"  
 Port = TypeInYourProxyPortAsANumber

 Dim Pr As New System.Net.WebProxy(Proxy, Port)  
 Pr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
 WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = Pr  
 Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

Obviously this is a client side proxy hack.

Haven't tried this on the server yet.